# Convergence of sequence of functions.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequence-of-function

Can someone explain to me why ${f_n}=x^{\frac{1}{2n-1}}$ defined on [-1,1] converges pointwise to $1$ if $x \in (0,1)$, to $-1$ if $x \in (-1,0)$, and to $0$ if $x=0$. This is the answer I got but I think it should converge to $1$ if $x \in [-1,1]-\{0\}$. Because there is an $N$ for which the exponent gets extremely small so it approaches $0$ (so anything raised to the $0$ power is $1$).

An intuitive explanation or a proof would be really appreciated.

Comment: note for odd powers, the sign cant change.

Comment: $x^{\frac{1}{2n-1}}$ can be, for $x\in(-1,1)$, written as $-\sqrt[2n-1]{-x}$. Therefore we can write a general formula $\mathrm{sgn}(x)\,\sqrt[2n-1]{\lvert x\rvert}$ for $x\in[-1,1]$. Do you see how to finish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're only confused about the convergence on $(-1,0)$, yes? The answer says pointwise convergence to $-1$ but you say $1$, yes? I will address this confusion below with both a proof, and an intuitive explanation.

Mathematically, we have convergence to $-1$ via the following. Let $x\in(-1,0)$, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{1/(2n-1)}=-\lim_{n\to\infty}|x|^{1/(2n-1)}=-(1)=-1$$ since the exponent $\frac{1}{2n-1}$ is always an odd root, so we can extract the $-1$ and just look at $|x|\in(0,1)$. Notice that we need to consider the limit with $|x|$ so that we can use continuity of $y\mapsto b^y$ for a fixed **positive** base $b$; if $b<0$ then $y\mapsto b^y$ is not continuous.

Intuitively, we can think about the following. Take some number $x\in(-1,0)$. Then when we take odd roots of $x$ we don't change its sign, because $(-1)^{1/(2n-1)}=-1$. So as $n$ grows $|x|$ is getting closer and closer to $1$, as we can see by the argument you give, however the sign of $x$ is always negative as $n$ grows, so we ultimately end up at $-1$.

Comment: Right I see... it makes sense now... Although before I read your answer this is what I was thinking: Look at the set $\{f_n(x)\}$ for all $n \in N$ and for some fixed $x \in (-1,0) $, then you can invoke the Monotone Convergence Theorem to show that it converges to $-1$. And apply this for each $x$ in the interval of definition. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yeah you could use monotone conv thm if you show the proper requirements of the thm. Although I think the approach I give is faster, but this is personal preference.

Comment: Yes, definitely your approach is faster, but I am trying to think this through carefully and it helps to tie it together with other things. I'm accepting your answer though, it solved my problem really nicely.